# Replace a column of an numpy array by the column of another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to replace the i-th column of an array A by the j-th column of an array B. Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [MCVE]. On top of that, your own attempt would be nice. This question is extremely low effort and will likely be downvoted and closed if it stays in its current state.

Comment: Are you simply trying to swap two axes? In numpy manual, you can find this:   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html

Comment: timgeb< , sorry i'm new on stackoverflow. I've read your link and i don't know what is wrong ? 
How my question could be clearer ? Should I have writen two lines of code to generate two array ? I think this is not an issue for people answering such question on numpy... There is also no relevant answer on google and the doc of numpy only show to concatenate a column, not how to replace it by another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this example for two 2d-arrays `a` and `b`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0, 16)
a.shape = (4, 4)

b = np.arange(16, 32)
b.shape = (4, 4)

print("a before:\n", a)
print("b before:\n", b)

i = 1
j = 2
a[:, i] = b[:, j]

print("a after:\n", a)
print("b after:\n", b)
```

Which prints:

```
a before:
 [[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
b before:
 [[16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31]]
a after:
 [[ 0 18  2  3]
 [ 4 22  6  7]
 [ 8 26 10 11]
 [12 30 14 15]]
b after:
 [[16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31]]
```

As you can see, `a` changed and has in column `i` (here `1`) the same values as `b` in column `j` (here `2`). `b` stayed the same.